# Youtube data api in android with retrofit

Tags: android, json, api, youtube, retrofit

I am using Youtube data API V3 in my android application. I am also using Retrofit for making requests to the API. I am able to communicate with the server but the response I am getting is not able to parse it.

```
public interface APIService {

    //////////////////////// Auth ///////////////////
    @GET("/youtube/v3/search")
    Call<JSONObject> getYoutbeFeeds(@Query("key") String developerKey, @Query("channelId") String channelId,@Query("part") String id,@Query("alt") String alt);
    /////////////////////////////////////////////
}
```

Fragment from where I am calling Youtube API

```
public class YoutubeFeedsFragment extends BaseFragment{

private APIService apiService = APIClient.getAPIService(Constants.YOUTUBE_FEEDS_URL);;


@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Call<JSONObject> callBack = apiService.getYoutbeFeeds(Constants.DEVELOPER_KEY,Constants.CHANNEL_ID,"id","json");
    Log.i("data", "service called");
    Log.i("data", callBack.toString());
    callBack.enqueue(new retrofit.Callback<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<JSONObject> response) {
            if(response.body() != null) {
                Log.i("data", "not null");

            }
            Log.i("data",response.data());

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"sorry connection problem",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Constants class

```
public class Constants {
    public static final String CHANNEL_ID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    public static final String DEVELOPER_KEY = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";

    public static String YOUTUBE_FEEDS_URL = "https://www.googleapis.com";
}
```

API Client building the URL

```
public class APIClient {
    public static APIService getAPIService(String baseUrl) {

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    client.interceptors().add(new LoggingInterceptor());

    if (apiService == null) {
        Retrofit restAdapter = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build();

        apiService = restAdapter.create(APIService.class);
    }
    return apiService;
}
```

I am getting response as null. When I am making the GET request from the Postman(REST API) I am getting the JSON. Please tell me how to parse the Youtube Data API response in Android using retrofit.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You used `.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())` which won't return a `JSONObject` but an already parsed json (via the Gson converter).
For example if your json must return something like:

```
{
  result: "searchResult"
}
```

Then you will create a class `Result` like this:

```
public class Result {

  @SerializedName("result")
  private String result;

  public String getResult(){
    return result;
  }

  public void setResult(String result) {
    this.result = result;
  }
}
```

And your `ApiService` will looks like this:

```
public interface APIService {

    //////////////////////// Auth ///////////////////
    @GET("/youtube/v3/search")
    Call<Result> getYoutbeFeeds(@Query("key") String developerKey, @Query("channelId") String channelId,@Query("part") String id,@Query("alt") String alt);
    /////////////////////////////////////////////
}
```

Comment: Thank You E-Kami but I am still not able to parse the response. In response I want links of all videos related to a channel but I am not able to get that

Comment: Well, the real issue lies in the way you wrote your request method. You cannot expect it to return a `JSONObject` as you used `addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())` in your retrofit initialisation. At least you can try to get a `JsonObject` (from the gson package). This tutorial resume clearly and simply how to use retrofit 2.0 http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/retrofit-2.0/en .I hope it helps